# Get the expansion of an alias (in both bash and zsh)

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, alias

I want to get the expansion of an alias.

For example, if I have:

```
alias g=hub
alias cdh='cd $HOME'
```

I want to have:

`expand_alias g` == `hub`

`expand_alias cdh` == `cd $HOME`

The tricky thing is that the two shells have different output:
bash:

```
$ alias g cdh
alias g='git'
alias cdh='cd $HOME'
```

zsh:

```
% alias g cdh
g=hub
cdh='cd $HOME'
```

Note no `alias`  prefix and no quotes around `hub`.

Comment: So what exactly are you missing?

Comment: Note that the `zsh` output is the standard one. `bash` will give you that one as well when in POSIX mode.

Comment: why are the single quotes a problem?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I want to define an alias based on the contents of an existing one.

Comment: why define aliases that way? aliases are meant for interactive use, and usually only set once in a config file. I don't see a use case for generating aliases from other aliases. I'm just trying to understand the problem..

Comment: As an example: I `alias g=` to  `hub` if it is installed, or`git` otherwise. I then want to prepend `exec_scmb_expand_args` if that function is defined to the `g` alias's text.

Comment: Note that `cd` without arguments already brings you to `$HOME`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I use the `enhancd` plugin which changes the default behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [Stéphane Chazelas' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/463391/143394), I came up with:

```bsh
function alias_expand {
  if [[ $ZSH_VERSION ]]; then
    # shellcheck disable=2154  # aliases referenced but not assigned
    [ ${aliases[$1]+x} ] && printf '%s\n' "${aliases[$1]}" && return
  else  # bash
    [ "${BASH_ALIASES[$1]+x}" ] && printf '%s\n' "${BASH_ALIASES[$1]}" && return
  fi
  false  # Error: alias not defined
}
```

(with bash 4.0 or newer).

Comment: function force-expand {
    local e="$(expand_alias "$1")" ;
    test -z "$e" && e="$1" ;
    echo "$e"
}

Comment: @HappyFace Cheers for pointing out the issue with the return value. Answer updated.

Answer (score 9):

In `zsh`, you can just use

```
get_alias() {
  printf '%s\n' $aliases[$1]
}
```

With `bash` (assuming it's not in POSIX mode in which case its `alias` would give an output similar to `zsh`'s), you could do:

```
get_alias() (
  eval '
    alias() { printf "%s\n" "${1#*=}"; }'"
    $(alias -- "$1")"
)
```

Basically, we evaluate the output of `alias` after having redefined `alias` as a function that prints what's on the right of the first `=` in its first argument.

You could use a similar approach for something compatible with most POSIX shells, `zsh` and `bash`:

```
get_alias() {
  eval "set -- $(alias -- "$1")"
  eval 'printf "%s\n" "${'"$#"'#*=}"'
}
```

Comment: I wondered why parentheses are used instead of the usual braces... a function body can be a single statement, and in this case that's a subshell.

Comment: @TomHale, that's to limit the scope of that `alias` function we declare.

Answer (score 0):

In my zsh environment, when I type `alias` with no command I get on `stdout` a list of all aliases. The same happens in bash (on MacOS both). These are in a form `alias=expansion`

So you could filter further with sed: `alias | sed -ne 's/cdh=\(.*\)$/\1/p'` if "cdh" is the alias you want to know. You could make a shell function in your profile for this, if this is a common task for you: like

```
expand_alias() { alias $@ | sed -ne 's/^'$@'=\(.*\)$/\1/p' }
```

Comment: This leaves the single quotes in. Please re-read the question.

Comment: @TomHale Inthe OP's example, it's not quite clear to me why the  single quotes are a problem. They don't hurt for single commands, or one word substitutions; they are needed for commands with spaces. So that's why I left in the spaces, as I don't want to complicate things by adding logic to remove unnecessary single quotes. If they always have to go, just add ` | tr -d \' ` to the pipe.

Comment: Fair enough assumption. I can't upvote you again now.

The `| tr` wouldn't allow for a `'` in the middle of an alias though.

Comment: this does not work as intended if there are `=` inside the alias. I will edit the answer with a fix for this :)

Answer (score 0):

How about defining a shell function:

```
EXA() { alias $@ | sed 's/^/expand_/; s/=/ == /; s/\o047//g; '; }
```

Comment: Syntax error when I copy and paste

Comment: show the syntax error.

Comment: `unmatched '`. How will this remove single quotes?

Comment: Rats! Corrected typo...

Comment: Breaks with: `alias ls='colourify ls -CF --block-size=\'\''1 --color=always --quoting-style=shell-escape'`

Answer (score 0):

My zsh had this bound to a key combo:

```
_expand_alias () {
    local word expl tmp pre sel what
    local -a tmpa suf
    eval "$_comp_setup"
    if [[ -n $funcstack[2] ]]
    then
        if [[ "$funcstack[2]" = _prefix ]]
        then
            word="$IPREFIX$PREFIX$SUFFIX"
        else
            word="$IPREFIX$PREFIX$SUFFIX$ISUFFIX"
        fi
        pre=()
    else
        local curcontext="$curcontext"
        if [[ -z "$curcontext" ]]
        then
            curcontext="expand-alias-word:::"
        else
            curcontext="expand-alias-word:${curcontext#*:}"
        fi
        word="$IPREFIX$PREFIX$SUFFIX$ISUFFIX"
        pre=(_main_complete - aliases)
    fi
    zstyle -s ":completion:${curcontext}:" regular tmp || tmp=yes
    case $tmp in
        (always) sel=r  ;;
        (yes | 1 | true | on) [[ CURRENT -eq 1 ]] && sel=r  ;;
    esac
    zstyle -T ":completion:${curcontext}:" global && sel="g$sel"
    zstyle -t ":completion:${curcontext}:" disabled && sel="${sel}${(U)sel}"
    tmp=
    [[ $sel = *r* ]] && tmp=$aliases[$word]
    [[ -z $tmp && $sel = *g* ]] && tmp=$galiases[$word]
    [[ -z $tmp && $sel = *R* ]] && tmp=$dis_aliases[$word]
    [[ -z $tmp && $sel = *G* ]] && tmp=$dis_galiases[$word]
    if [[ -n $tmp ]]
    then
        tmp=${tmp%%[[:blank:]]##}
        if [[ $tmp[1] = [[:alnum:]_] ]]
        then
            tmpa=(${(z)tmp})
            if [[ $tmpa[1] = $word && $tmp = $aliases[$word] ]]
            then
                tmp="\\$tmp"
            fi
        fi
        zstyle -T ":completion:${curcontext}:" add-space || suf=(-S '')
        $pre _wanted aliases expl alias compadd -UQ "$suf[@]" -- ${tmp%%[[:blank:]]##}
    elif (( $#pre )) && zstyle -t ":completion:${curcontext}:" complete
    then
        $pre _aliases -s "$sel" -S ''
    else
        return 1
    fi
}
```