# Why [[ -n $var ]] instead of [[ $var ]]?

Tags: zsh

In [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/464072/143394) I had some code which read:

```
if [[ $ZSH_VERSION ]]; then
```

This [was edited](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/464072/revisions#) to be:

```
if [[ -n $ZSH_VERSION ]]; then
```

**Update:** I just saw the edit comment:

> [[ x ]] didn't work until recently in zsh

I looked through the [`zsh` release notes](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/releases.html) and couldn't find reference to this.

Which `zsh` version first allowed `[[ x ]]`?

Comment: See e.g. https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/ChangeLog#L11593

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the `zsh` 5.5.1 docs for `CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS`

> For  compatibility, if there is a single argument that is not syntactically significant, typically a variable, the condition is treated as  a test for whether the expression expands as a string of non-zero length. In other words, [[ $var ]] is the same as [[ -n $var ]].  It is  recommended that the second, explicit, form be used where possible.

With the source tree around,

```
% grep -rl 'if there is a single argument' .
./Doc/Zsh/cond.yo
% git blame ./Doc/Zsh/cond.yo | grep 'if there is a single argument'
d082827c83 (Jun T             2014-05-18 22:03:35 +0900 198) For compat...
```

Inspection of `git log` shows that the code change went in a bit earlier than the documentation:

```
commit 9d47e8398d299e53ffe4e7ddf3731d2fedae9948
...
Date:   Tue May 13 08:16:50 2014 -0700

    32609: [[ $var ]] behaves as [[ -n $var ]] for bash/ksh compatibility
```

The mapping of the `ChangeLog` file to `git tag` is not clear to me, but it appears `zsh` 5.0.6 (Thu Aug 28 19:07:04 2014 +0100) is the first version with this change.

Comment: See `git tag --contains 9d47e8398d299e53ffe4e7ddf3731d2fedae9948` for the list of git tags that contain the commit. The `32609` is a reference to the mailing list: http://www.zsh.org/cgi-bin/mla/redirect?WORKERNUMBER=32609

Answer (score 1):

It is more explicit showing what the code is doing.

Personally, in this case I'd slightly prefer `[[ -n $ZSH_VERSION ]]` because it shows that it is testing for non-emptyness of the value of the var.

But I often have vars meant for boolean meaning in my scripts and I name them accordingly, like `is_logged_in` or `running_in_background`. If such vars are unset in my scripts they are `false`. And in such cases I prefer to use `[[ running_in_background ]]`, just because this reads better without the `-n` part, like a normal sentence:

```
if [[ running_in_background ]] ; then
    echo "something" | logger -t myprog
fi
```

But IMO it is just matter of taste, and as such should not have been edited: it's *your* code.

Comment: Well, OP quoted code by [another author](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%c3%a9phane-chazelas) and that same author then came in and changed it, so "your code" in this particular case means "both their code".  **;-) :-)**